# C#, List Instantiation from existing List?

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I'm trying to figure out what is happening in the code snippet below.

In the new list instantiation, it look's like they are referencing the other `coins` List?  I have never seen this before, what is the purpose?  Sorry if this has already been answer, if so please redirect me.  Thank you for your help.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> coins = new List<int>();
        List<int> amounts = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 10, 25, 50 };

        Change(coins, amounts, 0, 0, 51);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Change(List<int> coins, List<int> amounts, int highest, int sum, int goal)
    {
        if (sum == goal)
        {
            Display(coins, amounts);
            return;
        }

        if (sum > goal)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (int value in amounts)
        {
            if (value >= highest)
            {
                List<int> copy = new List<int>(coins);   // <<<<<<<
                copy.Add(value);
                Change(copy, amounts, value, sum + value, goal);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Display(List<int> coins, List<int> amounts)
    {
        foreach (int amount in amounts)
        {
            int count = coins.Count(value => value == amount);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",
                amount,
                count);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: They are creating a new copy of the source list so as when a new value is added to it, the original one is not modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a description of what the lines do.

```
 List<int> copy = new List<int>(coins);   // Creates a new list, initializing the values with the values in coins (creating a copy of coins).
 copy.Add(value);  // adds additional value to the copy.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx :

> List Constructor (IEnumerable)
>
> Initializes a new instance of the List class that contains elements copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity to accommodate the number of elements copied.

```
 List<int> copy = new List<int>(coins); // They are creating a copy of the list `coins`, called `copy`.
```